# Start with databases in visual basic 2012

Tags: database, visual-studio, sqlite

My story is: I just started with visual basic and worked with simple scripting languages like AS2-3 AutoIt even some simple programs in VB and C# but I have no idea about working with databases so I came to ask few question to jumpstart my coding engine.

1. Do I need to install any program or download any file to start working with databases?(researching about SQLite but still have no idea how to make it work)
2. What do you suggest for saving and recovering my variables on the disk in my standalone windows application?(even .txt files work for me ATM)
3. Is there any simple tutorial that explains usage of databases in standalone programs?

Comment: You could look into SQL Server Compact: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff687142.aspx . (I thought you don't need to install something extra, but don't shoot me if I'm wrong. Long time I used it.)

Comment: well it seems there is "SQL Server Compact" installed wia visual studio but I have no idea how to make a database and connect to it